# Can AWS lambda calls be Synchronous?

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Having some trouble using lambda functions in AWS. I would like to know if I can call AWS Lambda functions synchronously
rather than asynchronously. Right now the AWS Lambda functions seem to be continously running and I would like for a way to stop them
as they are using my credits. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

heres these code:

```
Client.GetObjectAsync(BucketName, FileName, (responseObj) =>
        {
        //print("about to get json");

            if (responseObj.Exception == null) print("exception not null"); else print(responseObj.Exception.Message);
            string data = null;
            var resp = responseObj.Response;
            if (resp == null)
            {
            //print("null");
            }
            else
            {
            //print("not null");
            }
        //print(resp.ContentLength);

            if (resp.ResponseStream != null)
            {
                print("before StreamReader");


                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.ResponseStream))
                {
                //print("In StreamReader");
                data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                //print("got json");
                }



            /**
            string fp = Application.dataPath + "\\unitydata.txt";
            using (var fs = System.IO.File.Create(@fp))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[81920];
                int count;
                while ((count = resp.ResponseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                fs.Flush();
            }
            **/

           // }
           // else
           // {
           //     print("response is null");
           // }
           // print("JSON CONTENT: " + data);
           // float[] fres = parseVectors(data);
           // for (int i = 0; i < fres.Length; i++) print(fres[i] + " ");
           // responseObj.ToString();
       // });
```

Comment: A good portion of your code is commented out, if it is not needed for the understanding of this question, I would advise you remove it instead so it doesn't clutter up the question.

Comment: This also looks like S3 fetching code rather than Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda function has a time out of 5 min. Since you stated that your Lambda function is continuously running, is it possible that your client code is doing this invocations behind the scenes?

Secondly, Please post details of your application technology stack. I see that you are using C# and AWS SDK for .NET. Are you writing a console application and trying to do few operations on S3?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know if I can call AWS Lambda functions synchronously rather than asynchronously.

> Making a call to AWS Lambda is always synchronous. Inside Lambda you
>   make asynchronous calls, but a call to Lambda is synchronous and upon
>   calling it will return a result or will fail in the maximum configured
>   time.

Right now the AWS Lambda functions seem to be continously running and I would like for a way to stop them as they are using my credits.

> You will be billed only for the time you use it. If you don't use it,
>   you will not be charged.